# Qt Creator does not show locals while debugging with gdb on Windows

Tags: debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I've recently run into the issue of not being able to use the debug view of Qt Creator. No Local Variables would show up and Expression Evaluators only work to some extent.

I've created this tiny C program to demonstrate the issue, though it happened in a standard Qt App as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int square, cube, i; // Breakpoint set in this line
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        square = i * i;
        cube = i * square;
        printf("i=%i \ti^2=%i \ti^3=%i\n", i, square, cube);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program in debug mode with GDB, it stops at the breakpoint as it should, it can be stepped forwards just fine, but no local variables are shown. This is **not** a debugger issue though, as I can easily get the variables if I run gdb from the command line. The expression evaluator does work somewhat: It shows you the value of an expression you type, though this expression then never gets updated if the variables change.

[This is how it looks like while debugging the program. You can see that the expressions work, but no locals are shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVe5e.png)

The versions I have installed are as follows:
OS: Windows 10
Qt: 5.10.0 for MinGW 32 bit
GCC: 5.3.0 MinGW 32 bit (I just installed the one that was recommended in the Qt installer)
GDB: 7.10.1 for MinGW 5.3.0
QtCreator: 4.5.0

I have tried exactly the same with newer versions of gcc and gdb, with exactly the same result. Also, the same thing happened with g++.

Does anyone know, how I could fix this? I really like working with QtCreator, but if I can't solve this problem, I'll probably have to revert to a different IDE.
Oh, and please tell me if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I added -O0 to compile flags, used a few other solutions people recommended but with no success. I changed something in debugger settings recently but cannot remember which ones. I finally have solved it a few minutes ago.

Go to Tools->Options->Debugger->GDB and clear the check of "Load system GDB pretty printers". Now I can see local and scope variables in the right pane after hitting a break point.